# I need a regex to capture just the number from a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I do not have access to the code, this is via an interface that only allows me to edit the regex that parses user responses. I need to extract the weight after users text, where they text things like:

`wt 172.5
172.5 lbs
180
wt. 173.22
172,5`

I need to capture the weight as a float field, but I want to restrict it to at most 1 decimal place. I tried using `/(?<val>[\d+((\.|,)\d\d?)?]/` but it is only saving the first digit "1" in the field

Comment: In future you may wish to wait awhile before selecting an answer. A quick selection may be followed by comments bringing out problems with the answer, may discourage other, possibly better answers and imo is a discourtesy to those still working on their answers. Many here wait at least a couple of hours. The point is that there is no rush.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks! New to the forum, this is helpful feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes what seems most simple is not. I suggest using this regex:

```
r = /(?<=\A|\s)\d+(?:[.,]\d)?(?=\d|\s|\z)/
```

We can alternatively define the regex using *extended* or *free-spacing* mode (by adding the modifier `x` after the final `/`), which allows us to include documentation:

```
r = /
    (?<=\A|\s)  # match beginning of string or space in a positive lookbehind
    \d+         # match one or more digits
    (?:[.,]\d)? # optionally (? after non-capture group) match a . or , then a digit
    (?=\d|\s|\z) # match a digit, space or the end of the string in a positive lookahead
    /x

"wt 172.5"[r]      #=> "172.5" 
"172.5 lbs"[r]     #=> "172.5" 
"180"[r]           #=> "180" 
"wt. 173.22"[r]    #=> "173.2" 
"172,5"[r]         #=> "172,5" 
"A1 143.66"[r]     #=> "143.6" 
"A1 1.3.4 43.6"[r] #=> "43.6"
```

Comment: I like it.  But!  What about '   .5    '?  You'd need to change your '\d+' to '\d*'

Comment: Mark, I intentionally did not match `' .5'`, but if you want to, your proposed change looks correct.

Comment: Thanks, Cary.  What I'm thinking is that "good enough" regexes are hard, perfect regexes are near to impossible.  I will only claim that my solution strives to be good enough.

Comment: @Mark, I don't strive for "perfect" regexes, just ones that meet the spec. Regular expressions comprise a programming language, just like Ruby, C or FORTH. Getting the result you want in any language may be "hard", but once you've gained sufficient experience with it and employ proper testing, it's all in a day's work.

Answer (score 0):

```
\d+(?:[,.]\d{1,2})?
```

Guess you wanted this .`[]` is character class,not what you think.Your character class captures just one out of all characters you have defined.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eB8xU8/12

Comment: Thanks! I'd found one place that suggested [] would capture anything enclosed, but your solution works great for capturing. Any thoughts on restricting captured data to 1 decimal place? my test of 183.235 saved all the digits

Comment: I don't think that this will capture the digits to the right of the decimal/comma -- and it does capture multiple digits to the right...

Comment: @vks, I did check the demo.  Your regex captures the 173.22.  "\d+" captures as many digits as it can.

Comment: My first comment references "to the right" and "to the right".  It should be "to the left" and "to the right".

Comment: OP says "but I want to restrict it to at most 1 decimal place".

Comment: @marklark its an easy fix replace by `\d` or `\d{1,2}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103983/discussion-between-marklark-and-vks).